# Update Codeigniter form - refresh

Tags: php

I'm having a form which retrieves the values from the database and updates it by submitting the form.

First time when I'm accessing the page, it works, it retrieves the values, but if I'm updating the values through the form it retrieves the new values only after refreshing manually the page.
How can I refresh it automatically?

Also, if I'm accessing the page, not doing an update, and refreshing it, everything it's deleted, including the values form the database.

This is the controller:

```
public function edit_profile()
{

    $id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $this->load->model('retrieve');

    $upd = array
   (
     'Name' => $this->input->post('name'),
     'surname' => $this->input->post('surname'),
     'Id_loc' => $this->input->post('id_loc')   
    );        

    $data['info']=$this->retrive->select_Info($id);           
    $this->retrieve->update_info($id,$upd);
    $this->load->view('edit_profile', $data);
```

}

And this is the model:

```
function update_info($id,$data){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('users', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code will look like this: with two functions

```
        public function edit_profile()
            {

               $id=$_SESSION['user_id'];        

                $data['info']=$this->retrive->select_Info($id);           
                $this->load->view('edit_profile', $data);
        }

    public function saveUpdate()
    {
    $id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
                $this->load->model('retrieve');

                $upd = array
               (
                 'Name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                 'surname' => $this->input->post('surname'),
                 'Id_loc' => $this->input->post('id_loc')   
                ); 
    $update = $this->retrieve->update_info($id,$upd);
if($update)
{
redirect('YURCTRLER/edit_profile');
}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

add the following code to your controller after an update is done:

```
redirect($this->uri->uri_string());
```

or

```
 redirect('YOURCONTROLLER/edit_profile', 'refresh');
```

For the case of deleting, the code you have provided I think is not enough to deduce the problem :-(

Comment: Ok.. If I'm trying the first one I get the "The localhost page isn’t working" error and the second one is an infinite refresh

Comment: I know why the second one is an infinite loop. Place the edit/update code in a new function, say saveupdate() and enter the update code, then `if($this->retrieve->update_info($id,$upd)){ redirect('YOURCONTROLLER/edit_profile');}`